# need help with basic use of TIdCmdTCPServer

Tags: delphi, indy

I'm working on a proof-of-concept app using TIdCmdTCPServer in delphi XE.

There seems to be something wrong with my code because only the first command works.  If i repeat the same command, it "times out".  See client code listing farther down below.

here's my command handler:

```
procedure TForm1.IdCmdTCPServer1CommandHandlersGetDateTimeCommand(ASender: TIdCommand);
begin
  ASender.Reply.SetReply(200, 'OK!');
  ASender.Reply.Text.Add(DateTimeToStr(Now));
  ASender.SendReply;  // I expect this must be redundant
end;
```

Here's the server component (nothing special here; I set the port # and created a command handler):

```
object IdCmdTCPServer1: TIdCmdTCPServer
  Bindings = <>
  DefaultPort = 7000
  CommandHandlers = <
    item
      CmdDelimiter = ' '
      Command = 'GetDateTime'
      Disconnect = False
      Name = 'TIdCommandHandler0'
      NormalReply.Code = '200'
      ParamDelimiter = ' '
      ParseParams = True
      Tag = 0
      OnCommand = IdCmdTCPServer1CommandHandlersGetDateTimeCommand
    end
  ExceptionReply.Code = '500'
  ExceptionReply.Text.Strings = (
    'Unknown Internal Error')
  Greeting.Code = '200'
  Greeting.Text.Strings = (
    'Welcome')
  HelpReply.Code = '100'
  HelpReply.Text.Strings = (
    'Help follows')
  MaxConnectionReply.Code = '300'
  MaxConnectionReply.Text.Strings = (
    'Too many connections. Try again later.')
  ReplyTexts = <>
  ReplyUnknownCommand.Code = '400'
  ReplyUnknownCommand.Text.Strings = (
    'Unknown Command')
  Left = 64
  Top = 8
end
```

here's the client code where the problem occurs:

```
  Client.Connect;
  try
    // retrieve welcome text
    memo1.lines.AddStrings(Client.LastCmdResult.Text);

    Client.SendCmd('GetDateTime', 200);
    memo1.lines.AddStrings(Client.LastCmdResult.Text);

    //////////////////////////// FAILS HERE (timeout)
    Client.SendCmd('GetDateTime', 200);
    memo1.lines.AddStrings(Client.LastCmdResult.Text);
  finally
    Client.Disconnect(true);
  end;
```

and the client component (nothing special here; i set the host & port #):

```
object Client: TIdCmdTCPClient
  ConnectTimeout = 1000
  Host = '127.0.0.1'
  IPVersion = Id_IPv4
  Port = 7000
  ReadTimeout = 1000
  CommandHandlers = <>
  ExceptionReply.Code = '500'
  ExceptionReply.Text.Strings = (
    'Unknown Internal Error')
  Left = 144
  Top = 96
end
```

Any ideas why is this happening?

Thank you!
mp

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You cannot use a `TIdCmdTCPClient` with a `TIdCmdTCPServer`.  `TIdCmdTCPClient` runs an internal thread that continuously reads from the connection, but the `SendCmd()` method also performs read operations of its own, so the two interfer with each other and grab each other's data.  That is why you get timeout errors. You need to change your client code to use a `TIdTCPClient` instead of a `TIdCmdTCPClient`.

Comment: thank you Remy!  i had not understood what you meant when you said this before to someone else.

Comment: >"You cannot use a TIdCmdTCPClient with a TIdCmdTCPServer". Really? What's the purpose of the TIdCmdTCPClient then? And why does the client component reads something automatically? Isn't this behaviour related to server side normally? I wanted to try out both components because I needed a small client-server application which sends simple commands but I didn't wanted to implement my own protocol. Even the docu for TIdTCPServer says to use the Cmd components, since the tcp only components do not offer protocols on application level.

Comment: The `Cmd` in the name refers to the `CommandHandlers` collection, which `TIdCmdTCPClient` and `TIdCmdTCPServer` both have. `TIdCmdTCPClient` is meant for protocols where the client socket connects to a server socket and then the client receives unsolicited/asynchronous packets from the server, which are processed by the client's `CommandHandlers`. The packets may or may not be responses to commands, but they do not follow the traditional client-command/server-response model used by most protocols. `TIdIRC` is an example of this...

Comment: ... Another example would be a traditional command/response model where the party roles are reversed - the server socket sends commands that the client socket responds to.  This might be useful in apps that implement NAT traversal techniques, where the roles might have to be swapped in order to make a TCP connection between parties when one is behind a NAT at the other is not.  Remember that TCP is bi-directional. It matters which party initiates the TCP connection to the other party, but once established it does not matter which party sends data to the other party and in which order.